# Tracing the source of unknown Sidekiq processes

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, redis, sidekiq

I have a service in production, hosted on AWS, that is supposed to run 2 Sidekiq processes: 1 on each of the two load-balanced machines. However, there seem to be 2 extra processes that I can't trace back to where they're originating from. I've tried rebooting both of the machines hoping it would kill any of the ghost processes, but the two unknown processes have remained alive, while the other two have restarted, so they are probably running somewhere else.

[image]

The ghost processes are causing issues raising 'Uninitialized constant: ', so it makes me think they do not have the application code and are connected by mistake. I've made them quiet for now.

How do I trace the source of these two processes? As you can see from the image, the host description is not very useful.

Comment: The issue was a new service that was accidentally sharing the same redis connection with the service in question (configuration copy-pasta). I would have been clearer if I had custom queue names instead of just leaving `default` everywhere. 

I will leave this question open in case folks have insights on how to debug this by inspecting the network or redis connections.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways which might help -

1. Redis client list - You could list all clients connected to the redis and filter by name, pid, age, db etc to get the IP address from where the connection was initiated.
   `redis-cli -h <redis-host> client list` and apply filters.
2. Logs - Sidekiq logs the process hostname (eg, `bc2e797afd0c`) and pid in logs. You could trace the log back to it's host using other identifiers like IP, container ID etc. which might be logged as well.